# Does it matter what state I set if both locations are in the same timezone

Tags: timezone

Is there any difference if I set the timezone to

- timezone: "America/New_York"

verses

- timezone: "America/Detroit"

Both States are in the same timezone but other than identifying exactly where you are in the timezone, what functionality does it offer?

UPDATE and FYI:

geonames.org does off the Timezone Id lookup which returns America/Detroit instead of America/New_York

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If some state has its timezone changed (by a law...) but not the other one (or if this happened in the past and you look at dates in the past), you'll get an incorrect timezone. Otherwise there are no differences.

Comment: I was thinking it might have to do with the offset in hours? http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/

Comment: @PhillPafford Being in the same timezone means that the offsets are constantly the same for both locations (this implies that they must also have the same DST rules, but this map doesn't show the details about these rules over the years).

Comment: FYI - you can read the specific rules with comments for both locations in the tz sources.  [Michigan is here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014f/northamerica#L921-L960) and [New York is here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2014f/northamerica#L253-L291).  The diffferences are mostly due to when Michigan used DST in the 1970's.